# Update single field in a Profile Update Form in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, updates, laravel-blade

I am trying to update a single field in my user profile form section in the Laravel app.

I can save fields correctly in DB but input values and placeholders are taking wrong values. In every hit Save, the values doesn' change, and they are taken from the last listed user profile details. In my case this is user#3.  The problem is when I log in with the user's #1 credentials, value and placeholder are taken from user #3. When I log in with user #2, again from user #3. Only values of user#3 are correct and I can manipulate it with no issues for both fields.

When i update the profile fields with user#1 it saves the entered one filed, but because the 2nd filed inherits the user#3 input details it saves it in field 2 of user#1 which makes a wrong entry. I can't leave null in those fields by default. My mass assignment is guarded.

How can save/update just a single field in the blade template without affecting the other fields in the form?

My routes:

`Route::get( '/profile', 'userController\\profileEdit@profileEdit')->name('profileEdit');`
`Route::post('/profile', 'userController\\profileEdit@update')->name('update');`

My controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\userController;
use App\Model\Hause_users;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class profileEdit extends Controller
{
    function profileEdit (Request $request){

        $user = Hause_users::all();
        $name = $request->session()->get('name');

        $request->session()->keep([request('username', 'email')]);

       return view('frontview.layouts.profile',['user'=>$user])->with('username' , $name );
    }



    function update (Request $request){

        $user = Hause_users::where('username', $request->session()->get('name'))->first();
        $user->fill(['email' => request('Email')]) ;
        $user->save();


        $user->phone;
        //dd($user->phone->phone);

        if ($user->phone === null) {
            $user->phone->phone->create(['phone' => request('tel')]);
        }
        else{
            $user->phone->update(['phone' => request('tel')]);
        }
        return back()->withInput();
   }
```

Blade file: `

```
@extends('frontview.layouts.userView')
@extends('frontview.layouts.default')

@if ($errors->any())
<div class="alert alert-danger">
<ul>
@foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
<li>{{ $error }}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
</div>
@endif



@section('title')

@endsection

@section('content')

    @foreach($user as $v )


    @endforeach

    <h2 class="form-group col-md-6">Здравей, {{$username }} </h2>


    <form class = "pb2" method="POST" name = 'profile' action='profile'  >

        {{ csrf_field()}}
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="inputEmail4">Поща</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name = "Email" id="inputEmail4"
                       value="{{$v['Email']}}"
                       placeholder="{{$v->Email}}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="inputPassword4">Промени Парола</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Парола">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputAddress">Address</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name = "Adress"  id="inputAddress" placeholder="Снежанка 2">
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="inputAddress">Телефон</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name = 'tel' value="{{$v->phone['phone']}}"
                   placeholder="{{$v->phone['phone']}}"
                   id="example-tel-input" >
            </div>      
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="inputCity">Град</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity">
                <label for="inputCity">Квартал</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity">
            </div>

            {{--<div class="col-md-6" >--}}
                {{--<label for="image">Качи снимка</label>--}}
                {{--<input type="file" name = "image">--}}
                {{--<div>{{$errors->first('image') }}</div>--}}
            {{--</div>--}}

        </div>      
                {{--<div ><img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/placeholder-avatar.jpg"--}}
                         {{--class="rounded-circle z-depth-1-half avatar-pic" alt="example placeholder avatar">--}}
                {{--</div>--}}
                {{--<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">--}}
                    {{--<div class="btn btn-mdb-color btn-rounded float-left">--}}
                        {{--<span>Add photo</span>--}}
                        {{--<input type="file">--}}
                    {{--</div>--}}
                {{--</div>--}}
            {{--</div>--}}

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck">
                    Запомни ме!
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>  

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Запази</button>
    </form>
@endsection
@section('name')
    {{ $username }}
@endsection
```

**Output summary**:

On img#1 are the correct entry details . This is other section not the Profile edit one. Currently loged user is U#1 but as you can see on image 2, values and placeholder of both fields are for the U#3. When i hit the blue button U#1 saves the untouched filed input of U#3. Same is when i log in with U#2.

[image: Correct outputs]

[image: Profile edit secion]

Comment: Do user 1 and user 3 have the same name? I see you select by name(`$user = Hause_users::where('username', $request->session()->get('name'))->first();`), while it is more conventional to use an ID(to prevent finding the wrong record). Also, you are using `$request->session()->get('name')` to retrieve the form data, while I think you want to use the `$request->get('name')`, since you are posting it with the form.

Comment: No they have different names. first() does not support fill method as far as i know. What will happen if i set the Email column to be nullable() ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the answer here is quite simple. What i am doing wrong is that i am not passing the value of the currently logged user to the view correctly. On my profileEdit method i was using `$user = Hause_users::all();` and then looping trough all id's into the view and then fetching every field. But because the view doesn know which user passes the data, the foreach always returns the last user id from the array  with its input, no matter which user is currently logged in. Then the data was overridden with wrong inputs.
The solution is also simple. 
Instead of `$user = Hause_users::all();` 
i have used
`$user = Hause_users::where('username', $request->session()->get('name'))->first();`

and then into view i was objecting the $user variable without any loops like this:

```
 <form class = "pb2" method="POST" name = 'profile' action='profile'  >
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        {{--<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH">--}}
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="inputEmail4">Поща</label>
                <input type="Email" class="form-control" name = "Email" id="inputEmail4"
                       value="{{$user->Email}}"
                       placeholder="{{$user->Email}}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="inputPassword4">Промени Парола</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Парола">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputAddress">Address</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name = "Adress"  id="inputAddress" placeholder="Снежанка 2">
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="inputAddress">Телефон</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name = 'tel' value="{{$user->phone['phone']}}"
                   placeholder="{{$user->phone['phone']}}"
                   id="example-tel-input" >
```

Basically this is a detailed explanation to all that not using the built in Auth system of Laravel